# We’ve had the house painted. (The house is already painted?)

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect

> We’ve had the house painted.

The house is already painted? or We don't know the status of the house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the house is already painted.  It's the same as any other use of the present perfect: "I have Xed" means that the action of Xing is complete.

"I have eaten" = the action of eating is complete
"I have seen" = the action of seeing is complete
"I have had (something done)" = the action of causing it to happen is complete